# parseFloat returns NaN (when parsing a document style size)

Tags: javascript

the body style parseFloat keeps returning NaN when it should be -0.1 or 0.1 when I print it in console.log, I'm most-likely just getting tired, but I can't see the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated as always,
Also not looking for a jQuery answer here, this must be JS

```
function startUp() {
    var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer");
    for (var i=0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer")[i].addEventListener("click", resizeText);
    }
};

window.onload = startUp;

function resizeText() {
    var fontChange = parseFloat(this.value);
    console.log(fontChange);
    if (document.body.style = "") {
        document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-size:1.0em;");
    }
    var currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize.replace('em', ''));
    console.log(currentFontSize);
    document.body.style.fontSize = (currentFontSize + fontChange) + "em";
};
```

and the html

```
<div id="fontbuttons">
 <input class="fontsizer" value="-0.1" type="image" id="fontdown" alt="-" src="fontdown.png" />
 <input class="fontsizer" value="0.1" type="image" id="fontup" alt="+" src="fontup.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: ... so what is `document.body.style.fontSize.replace('em', '')`?

Comment: Not your issue, but `document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer")[i]` should be `fontButtons[i]` for efficiency.

Comment: `document.body.style = ""` assigns an empty string to replace the body's style object. Do you *really* want to do that?

Comment: Not an efficient solution but try `addEventListener("click", resizeText(this));` and `function resizeText(t) {
    var fontChange = parseFloat(t.value);`

Comment: I first need to check if there is an empty style object, if there is assign font size to it. then I'm trying to get the body tags style font size and use currentFontSize as a variable to let a user + or - font size with the 2 buttons provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** `=` is assignment, so this line actually mean clear body style.

```
if (document.body.style = "") {
```

And then it returns the assigned value (empty string) to the `if` statement, whereas `""` is a falsy value, so the check is actually `if(false) {...`. You'll never have font size set.

You should use `==` or `===` to compare

```
if (document.body.style == "") {
```

**2** `document.body.style` is an object, it should never be equal to empty string. You should compare `document.body.style.fontSize` with it.

**3** Use `document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em"` over `document.body.setAttribute`. Because `setAttribute` only changes the HTML attribute while what you want is DOM property.

> EDIT: I missed a thing, as pointed out by **Roko C. Buljan**. When you set font size in CSS, `document.body.style.fontSize` will still be emtpy string, unless you manipulate it with JS. You'd better compare with computed style, the solution is addressed in his answer.

```js
function startUp() {
    var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer");
    for (var i = 0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) {
        fontButtons[i].addEventListener("click", resizeText);
    }
};

window.onload = startUp;

function resizeText() {
    var fontChange = parseFloat(this.value);
    console.log(fontChange);

    if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }

    var currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize.replace('em', ''));
    console.log(currentFontSize);
    document.body.style.fontSize = (currentFontSize + fontChange) + "em";
};
```

```html
<div id="fontbuttons">
 <input class="fontsizer" value="-0.1" type="button">
 <input class="fontsizer" value="0.1" type="button">
</div>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: @dav3ydark007 updated a little to explain what really happens when compare with `=` operator. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: NOTE that `document.body.style.fontSize` will always return `""` even if you already set it in CSS like I explained in my answer. So if one sets for `body` a size like `1.2em` be ready to expect weird results.

Comment: Much better understanding thanks, I was definitely misunderstanding a few things

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good call! Should compare with computed style, otherwise the first click may bring a big jump.

Comment: @LeoDeng you should follow my example if you're really picky about that things. Also to give you a tip: All browsers have a default 16px for `body`, which equals to 1em, so for every `px` value that is returned by *getCompSt* you simply do getCompSt/16 = your needed em conversion :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know it, I just missed that. Practically, I may not directly read style in both ways. For example, if a user uses text zooming, he may have problem with eyesight, so we might consider remember his zooming set, either by cookie, localStorage, or anything else. And the zooming shouldn't be unlimited by the way. On the other hand, I may use dataset to store runtime data to HTML. And by the way computedStyle may cause reflow/repaint even if you just read something from it. For me it's really the last resort.

Comment: @LeoDeng I don't understand your comment about eyesight people resizing the window (CTRL +/-), the font-size will not change... http://jsbin.com/sokivi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Some people don't know the hotkey, really. That's why you could see so many sites provide in-page text zooming feature.

Comment: @LeoDeng Therefore dav3ydark007 will not use such script ;)

Comment: @dav3ydark007 I'm not sure. However the biggest purpose here is to learn how to deal with problems and why, not only get the job done. So, either he uses or not, help people improve is the most important thing. :)

Comment: Agreed, I'm on here to learn, as I am very new to programming with php / JS, I understand things here and there but I want to become more efficient and better programmer, Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say we have the font-size set at `1.2em`

```
/*CSS:*/ body{ font-size: 1.2em; }
```

in **JS** if you test:

```
console.log( document.body.style.fontSize ); // *(and empty string)*
```

So you need to do like:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null);    
console.log( style.fontSize ); // "19.2px"
```

***bummer***, but we expected `em`, right?

For every browser sets the default font size to `16px` ([google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=default%20font-size%20for%20all%20browsers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BSuBVJX0BrCo8wegwYLoDQ)) you can retrieve *any* `em` value by simply dividing the `px value` that is returned by our `getComputedStyle` by 16.

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null); // .fontSize = "19.2px"
var currentFontSize_EM = parseFloat( style.fontSize ) / 16  // 1.2

document.body.style.fontSize = (currentFontSize_EM + fontChange) + "em";
```

**that' s it.**